# Spark hashingTF and why it is different from TF that is used to calculate term frequency of a word

Tags: python, pyspark, hash, nlp, bigdata

I'm working with a dataframe containing a column called words, where each row represents a tweet, and it stores a list of words or tokens extracted from that tweet. I applied HashingTF (Spark) to analyze the results, and the outcome is shown in the table below. The second column, features, represents the results of applying HashingTF.

[image]

My understanding, based on the documentation, is that when you provide HashingTF with a list of tokens, it first hashes each token and then calculates term frequency (TF). However, the results I obtained indicate that for each token, it only reflects the number of times that token is repeated in each row/list, and not the TF.

According to [[2]](https://tfidf.com/), TF is calculated as follows: TF = (Number of repetitions of a word in a document) / (# of words in a document).

Considering that each row in my dataframe represents a document, am I overlooking something here? Additionally, why is it necessary to hash the words? Especially considering that sometimes different words are hashed to the same value?